# Unknown layer: ReLU

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I have modified some of the layers in MobileNet model a little bit to use on server with Node.js. I get an error: **Unknown layer: ReLU** when i try to load model by using **tf.loadModel()** function:

```
model = await tf.loadModel('http://localhost:80/models/MobileNet/model.json');
```

I tried modifying the **modelTopology.class_name** parameter in model.json file but doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Could you provide full trackeback error and the model.json ?

Comment: Can you check this issue https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/267#issuecomment-459446704